# Нет атрибутов у модели Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

У меня такая ситуация создал класс

```
class NewsService extends Model {

/**
 * @param \common\models\News
 */
private $_newsModel;

/**
 * NewsService constructor.
 * @param array $config
 */
public function __construct($config = []) {

    parent::__construct($config);

    if(isset($config['id']) && $config['id']) {
        $this->_newsModel = News::findOne($config['id']);
        $this->setAttributes($this->_newsModel->getAttributes());
    }
    else {
        $this->_newsModel = new News();
    }
}

public function rules()
{
    return $this->_newsModel->rules();
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return $this->_newsModel->attributeLabels();
}
```

В контролере создаю эту модель, но вылетает ошибка, что нету атрибутов

```
 public function actionCreate()
 {
    $model = new NewsService();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->validate()) {
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);
 }
```

> Getting unknown property: common\models\service\NewsService::title

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как оказалось нужно было добавить все атрибуты в свойства класса NewsService

```
<?php
namespace common\models\service;

use \common\models\News;
use \yii\base\Model;
use \common\models\service\Translit;



class NewsService extends Model {

public $id;
public $date_created;
public $date_update;
public $title;
public $description;
public $content;
public $image;
public $isNewRecord;
public $status;
public $article_or_news;
public $url;

/**
 * @param \common\models\News
 */
private $_newsModel;

/**
 * NewsService constructor.
 * @param array $config
 */
public function __construct($config = []) {

    parent::__construct($config);

    if(isset($config['id']) && $config['id']) {
        $this->_newsModel = News::findOne($config['id']);
        $this->setAttributes($this->_newsModel->getAttributes());
    }
    else {
        $this->_newsModel = new News();
        $this->attributes = $this->_newsModel->attributes;
    }
}

public function rules()
{
    return $this->_newsModel->rules();
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return $this->_newsModel->attributeLabels();
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если включено кэширование схем БД, то можно попробовать почистить кэш.

Объект `NewsService` вы создаете без параметров, следовательно в `$model` у вас будет лежать объект `News` (нужен код этого класса), затем происходит рендер отображения `create`, без валидации и сохранения модели. В отображении вы скорее всего обращаетесь к полю `title`, с которым какие-то проблемы в `News`.

Comment: Да нету вроде никаких проблем

news модель сгенерил с помощью gii

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['date_created', 'date_update'], 'safe'],
            [['title', 'description', 'content'], 'required'],
            [['status'], 'boolean'],
            [['article_or_news'], 'integer'],
            [['content', 'url', 'title', 'description', 'image'], 'string'],
        ];
    } - привила валидации

Comment: Значит нужны магические методы __get() и __set() для получения поля title в NewsService, т.к. NewsService::title не сущесвтует, оно у вас лежит в NewsService::_newsModel, к которому можно обратиться в отображении через $model->_newsModel->title